# Create new column from specific rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file where each row represents a property followed by a variable number of subsequent rows that reflect rooms in the property. I want to create a column that, for each property, summates the gross floor area of each room. The unstructured nature of the data is making this difficult to achieve in `pandas`. Here is an example of the table I have at the moment:

```
id  ba  store_desc      floor_area
0   1   Toy Shop        NaN
1   2   Retail Zone A   29.42
2   2   Retail Zone B   31.29
3   1   Grocery Store   NaN
4   2   Retail Zone A   68.00
5   2   Outside Garden  83.50
6   2   Office          7.30
```

Here is the table I am trying to create:

```
id  ba  store_desc      floor_area   gross_floor_area
0   1   Toy Shop        NaN          60.71
3   1   Grocery Store   NaN          158.8
```

Does anybody have any pointers on how to achieve this result? I'm totally lost.

Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC

```
df1=df[df['floor_area'].isnull()]

df1['gross_floor_area']=df.groupby(df['floor_area'].isnull().cumsum())['floor_area'].sum().values

df1
Out[463]: 
   id  ba    store_desc  floor_area  gross_floor_area
0   0   1       ToyShop         NaN             60.71
3   3   1  GroceryStore         NaN            158.80
```

Answer (score 1):

First made a temporary column named category which I then forward filled, grouped by that column to get the sum,  and then mapped that back to the relevant store_desc values.

```
df['category'] = df[df.floor_area.isnull()]['store_desc']

df['category'].fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)

df['gross_floor_area'] = df.store_desc.map(df.groupby('category').sum().floor_area)

df.drop('category',axis=1,inplace=True)

df[df.gross_floor_area.notnull()]
```